# Postgresql: One-To-Many Relationship With Multiple Conditions On The Many Side

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, relational-division, in-subquery

I have a Students table that has the following columns

```
id
student_name
```

And Courses table

```
id
student_id  //a foreign key
course_name
credits
```

It is a one to many relationship(one student might have multiple courses).

I want to list all the students that have these 2 courses

```
first course:   course_name -> math    , credit -> 5
second course:  course_name -> history , credit -> 3
```

Please note that each student has to have at least these two courses.

I can get what I want by joining with the Courses table twice(once for the first course and another for the second course), but in case I want to add one more course to the condition I will need to join one more time.

So can you please guide me to another approach.

Comment: Do you want each student to have **exactly** those two courses, or _at least_ those two courses (but could have more)

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but shouldn't that be a many-to-many relationship? One course can contain multiple students and one student enrolls with multiple courses

Comment: At least these 2 courses

Comment: True, it is better to be many to many, but I just used this example to make the question simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this solve your problem? I count all occurrences for your expected courses and the sum must be `2`.

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=62cc62603ccfcaf0d53f3819b298f870)

```
SELECT
    s.id
FROM students s
JOIN courses c
ON c.student_id = s.id
GROUP BY s.id
HAVING SUM(
    ((c.course_name = 'math' AND c.credits = 5)
    OR
    (c.course_name = 'history' AND c.credits = 3))::int
) = 2
```

Alternative to the `SUM(condition::int)` you could use the `COUNT()` with a `FILTER` clause:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=3e248f3f1f9fb5fd25c47bcb2c07dd96)

```
HAVING COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE
    (c.course_name = 'math' AND c.credits = 5)
    OR
    (c.course_name = 'history' AND c.credits = 3)
) = 2
```

Comment: thanks for effort you put on the answer, it looks fine in the demo, but to make it work for my case I am trying to understand how the sum is being 2 when you are using OR, so I tried this ````select (true or true)::int as x ```` and it is giving me 1 as I expected. can you please explain how are you getting the sum 2?

Comment: You're right: The bool condition gives 0 or 1. Since `student _id == 2` (in my fiddle) matches this condition twice (first for the `math`, second for the `history` record), the sum of two matches is 2. So, if you need to add a third condition, the sum must be 3, because the table must meet the condition three times. I added the intermediate step here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=b7f607ed9d2b35a389bb74635b1ecbcc

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the elegant solution